# How to read multiple SQL statements from a file and execute in pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon

I am new to pentaho and I have a requirement to read multiple SQL statements from a file and store the output in a file or datastore. Output/select columns are common for all the sql statements. May I know how to achieve it. 
E.g

```
Select last_name, first_name age from employee where age is > 25;
Select last_name, first_name age from employee where salary is > 25000;
Select last_name, first_name age from employee where deptid in (Select deptid from dept where deptid like 'Dept-E00%');
```

The data that I need to load is huge (25 million/day) and the above SQL statements are just samples. Selecting all the rows and applying filters on each row is not an option for me.

A .ktr file is much helpful.

Thanks in advice.

Answer (score 4):

You can also try as below:

1. Read all the SQL queries into a memory using the "**Copy rows to result**". Check the image as below:

[image]

2. In a separate transformation, define a variable and **check** : `execute for every input row` and `copy previous result to parameter`.
3. Finally, Take a "**Table Input Step**" and use that variable as defined above. Check the image below:

[image]

Here i have used `${queries}` as the variable.

Note: Assuming that the output step metadata structure will remain the same. If it is changing, i assume it won't work.

I assume this process will scale up for millions of record. I haven't tried it for this huge volume, but you can give it a try.

Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/rishuatgithub/b677078f637e8031c17e) of the code as shown above.

You can read [this blog](https://anotherreeshu.wordpress.com/2014/12/23/using-copy-rows-to-result-in-pentaho-data-integration/) also, in case you need to know more.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: interesting take. I agree, this probably scales up better.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the SQL scripts by using the "Execute row SQL script". It'll run every script in sequential order and return the resultset of them all into a single data stream. I suggest you add a constant field to each of those SQL statements to include a description of what they refer to, as I'm not sure the Execute Row SQL script will include the SQL statement in the output stream.

Comment: i am a bit doubtful on the scaling up of the "Execute SQL / Execute Row SQL" step, when it comes to loading millions of volumes of data. Though i am not sure 100%, but please have a look at my solution below and give your thoughts to it. !!